# Select MAX TIMESTAMP as BIGINT from SQL table

Tags: sql-server, timestamp, max, bigint

I am worried about the performance of the following query:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CAST((CONVERT(bigint, DBTimeStamp)) AS decimal)) AS DBTimeStamp 
FROM Category 
WHERE DepartmentID = 5
```

Is there a faster way of getting the biggest/latest timestamp as integer from a table?

Comment: Just use `SELECT MAX(CAST(DBTimestamp AS BIGINT)) ....` ...

Comment: NB, TIMESTAMP is deprecated from SQL 2005, you should use/refer to ROWVERSION when possible. A quick way to find the latest (max) value is to access the @@DBTS function but this is per database not table.

Comment: I am working with a 2005 database an I cannot change its structure so I have to stick with this, but thanks. I will keep in mind for newer versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you calculate the max befor the converting and casting SQL can use an index and only need to convert and cast once:

```
SELECT 
CAST(CONVERT(bigint,MAX( DBTimeStamp)) AS decimal) AS DBTimeStamp 
FROM Category 
WHERE DepartmentID = 5
```